# Bug transition when i use default theme with react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

when I press the sign up or sign in button, we can see the initial screen stay for 1 second.
I use the default theme to put my stack navigator in transparent and see my image in the background (this is the only solution that works, no backgroundColor: transparent works).

I would like to keep the transition of the screens.

observe the gray frame on the picture [first pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc0CD.png)
[second pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwDCH.png)

App.js :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ImageBackground, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import AuthNavigator from './navigation/AuthNavigator';

const navTheme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    background: 'transparent',
  },
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <ImageBackground
        source={require('./assets/fond-1.png')}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      >
        <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
        <NavigationContainer theme={navTheme}>
          <AuthNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </ImageBackground>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

AuthNavigator.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import AuthIndex from '../screens/AuthScreens/AuthIndex';
import SignUp from '../screens/AuthScreens/SignUp/SignUp';
import SignIn from '../screens/AuthScreens/SignIn/SignIn';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function AuthNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="AuthIndex"
      screenOptions={{
        headerTitle: '', // hide the title by setting it to an empty string
        headerBackTitleVisible: false, // hide back title
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerShadowVisible: false,
        headerTransparent: true, // make header transparent
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="AuthIndex" component={AuthIndex} />
      <Stack.Screen name="AuthSignUp" component={SignUp} />
      <Stack.Screen name="AuthSignIn" component={SignIn} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

setting the animation to 'none' works but that's not what I want. I would like to keep the animation, that it is as fluid as initially